# Angular Kendo UI: Display X instead of text in masktextbox

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I am using Angular Kendo MaskTextbox to mask number in input textbox. I want to display X instead of number in input Box

OUTPUT Needed:
(123) 456-78-90-12 to be displayed as (XXX) XXX-XX-90-12 in input textbox

[Kendo Angular MaskTextbox](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/maskedtextbox/)

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <p>Enter phone number</p>
        <kendo-maskedtextbox [mask]="mask" [value]="value"></kendo-maskedtextbox>
    `
})

class AppComponent {
    public value: string = "359884123321";
    public mask: string = "(999) 000-00-00-00";
}
```

Comment: is it read-only or you can actually edit that number, like a password, for example, you are typing but you cant see what are you typing?

Comment: yes i want to make it like password

Comment: The answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113132/partial-password-masking-on-input-field might be a good starting point